# Counting Time Spent in the Debugger

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I have a Windows program that does animation. It uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get the current time and determine how much time has passed since the last animation tick. When I am debugging the program and I stop at a breakpoint for a while the next animation tick will be extremely long once I continue execution (i.e. it includes the time spent with execution paused in the debugger).

Often this results in missing events that occur shortly after the point in time the breakpoint was hit. It also makes it impossible to step 'tick by tick' through an animation.

What are some ways to avoid this type of problem? Is there a mechanism by which I can count the time spent in the debugger so I can subtract it from the programs internal time logic?

Specifically, I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve 'clamping the timestep'. My fallback is to use `IsDebuggerPresent` and simply clamp large ticks to some predefined duration, but I'd like to see if there is dedicated API or a clever trick to do this in a more robust way. Ideally there would just be some Visual C++ extension/intrinsic that was just `TimeElapsedWithExecutionSuspended`.

Comment: "I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve 'clamping the timestep'." why?